# PHPMailer and function escapeshellcmd()

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use new version of PHPMailer. On the server, I get an error:

> Warning: escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons in /public_html/library/email/class.phpmailer.php on line 1442

Is there a function that could replace `escapeshellcmd()` ?

Comment: are you using a hosted provider? in these two links it states that possibly the host does not want you using this mailer and to switch to switch to using the mail or SMTP transports. Hope this helps. https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=900365 or https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/596

Answer (score 4):

No, [`escapeshellcmd()` has some inherent problems](https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36) which make it worth disabling for many, but you can work around it a different way: **use SMTP to localhost instead**.

By default PHPMailer uses the PHP `mail()` function for sending, which calls a local sendmail binary via a shell (requiring the use of `escapeshellcmd()`), which in turn opens a synchronous SMTP connection to your mail server on localhost. You can skip much of this by sending directly to localhost yourself, bypassing the shell overhead. Do this:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
```

Other settings should work with defaults. Two advantages of using SMTP to localhost are that you can get much better feedback on the submission process (with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`), and it's also faster than using `mail()`.

Comment: Temporarily I wanted to get around it that way. It is a pity that there is no other way for this function

Comment: Not at all - SMTP to localhost is faster and more controllable, provides better feedback, and is better in almost every way. The only reason it's not the default is because it's very marginally more complex to set up. `escapeshellcmd` is essentially broken, so you should be happy to be able to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an older version. I used Version: 5.2.6  and it works.