# PHP Mailer [escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons]

Tags: php, phpmailer

First of all, hi and thanks for your time, yesterday I have installed PHP Mailer 6.0.5, by running composer locally then I uploaded the vendor folder that it generated on my server, but when I try to run phpmailer it say: `escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons` , here is my code:

```
require '/.../.../public_html/vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->addAddress($_POST['Email']);
$mail->setFrom('.......');
$mail->Subject=".....";
$mail->Body=".....";
if ($mail->send()) {
.....
   }
```

How can I solve this error, could it depend on my installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer and function escapeshellcmd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846441/phpmailer-and-function-escapeshellcmd)

Answer (score 1):

source https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/966

use:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

that way PHPMailer will send via SMTP to localhost, which does not involve calling escapeshellcmd.

Comment: turn on error reporting (verbose) of PHPMailer to track down the problem: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`

Comment: error:2018-07-06 07:37:48 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: make sure you have all settings in place - and some you should try to see which works for you (e.g. SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587) , ref https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps

Comment: The problem is that I don't wont use the SMTP, because I have limitations, but the strange thing, is  that if I don't use SMTP method, but I use Standard method, I still get error, but the email is sent!How can I delete/fix this error?