# Error when mailing - escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, laravel, email

Encountering the below while sending email for email verification.

> "escapeshellcmd() has been disabled for security reasons"

It's frustrating and I am not able to solve it on my own. Any help is appreciated...

Screenshot of the error.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer and function escapeshellcmd()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846441/phpmailer-and-function-escapeshellcmd)

Comment: did u resolve problem?

Comment: No. Not yet resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

and PHPMailer will send via SMTP to localhost, which does not involve calling `escapeshellcmd`.

Take a look if your `config/mail.php` look like that:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
```

Comment: how to do this?
Please tell me the steps.. Please

Comment: you need to do this in your mailer logic, it is mail issue

Comment: Take a look in mail configuration, maybe somewhere is enough to add "smtp"